# Is there an analytic form for the squared error of the difference of two univariate Gaussians?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, gaussian-integral

Using [anchored ensembling](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11324) it is possible to estimate the mean $\mu$ and the variance $\sigma^2$ of a output. I had the insight than if I then sampled from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, I could estimate both the aleatoric (data) and epistemic (model) uncertainty in one shot and use it to guide exploration. I could do this optimization using samples, but it has occurred to me that propagating uncertainty through the [TD error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_difference_learning) might result in much less variance in the gradients.

Thanks to the [uncertainty propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty) page I understand how that might be done, but I am missing the last step which is the cost function.

At first glance it might seem that the sixth [example formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Example_formulas) ($f=aA^b$) should be enough to derive the squared error, but it is obvious to me that this would just pull the variance downward if I used it as cost directly.

How do I integrate: $E_{a \sim N({\mu_1},{\sigma_1}),b \sim N({\mu_2},{\sigma_2})}(a - b)^2$? I am hoping for something neat that I could backprop through.

Comment: No. I am assuming that p(a) and p(b) are univariate Gaussian distributions, but have different means and variances. I've changed the question to better reflect what I am asking.

Comment: Then $\mathbb{E}(a-b)^2=(\mu_1-\mu_2)^2+\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2$ (if $a,b$ are independent).

Comment: That seems really convenient, but it can't be right. It is obvious to me that to minimize that function you'd just set the two ${\sigma}$s to zero. This would be the case even if the two ${\mu}$s were held constant. If I sampled instead and optimized through those then the variances could grow. It is not a matter of them being independent either. Am I asking something wrong here?

Comment: By can't be right, I mean it can't be right as an optimization target for the task I am trying to solve. Not that I do not believe that the equation is right.

Comment: The example formula you reference ($f=a A^b$) is in the "nonlinear" section, you describe something that is linear and there is an exact formula as @metamorphy has given you.

Comment: Indeed it is not clear if you asking how to compute $\mathbb{E}(X-Y)^2$ for two independent normal RVs $X$ and $Y$, which is answered by metamorphy (I really encourage, in general, the use of capital letters for RVs and lower-case letters for the values they take on, as it is one very popular convention) or if you are asking about some optimization problem that is left unspecified or only implicitly stated behind four links to other topics.

Comment: The way this played out is fine, I was just so surprised at how different the effects of optimizing the sampling and the analytic would be. As it turns out, probably I should not be doing ensemble linking by sampling through a Gaussian (which would optimize for epistemic and aleatoric uncertainty) but by randomly sampling networks without replacement (which would only optimize for epistemic uncertainty) instead. So all is well that ends well, I suppose.